# Changing the dataset of a ggplot object

Tags: r, graphics, plot, ggplot2

I'm ploting subsets of my data with `ggplot2` and I was wondering if I would somehow use all the options already contained in a `ggplot` object in a subset of the original data. As an example, take this is first plot (code chunk 1):

```
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, color=factor(cyl))) + geom_point(shape=21, size=4)
print(p)
```

Now I want to make a second plot with a subset of `mtcars`, so I would normally do this (code chunk 2):

```
new_data <- subset(mtcars, disp > 200)
p <- ggplot(new_data, aes(mpg, wt, color=factor(cyl))) + geom_point(shape=19, size=4)
print(p)
```

It seems a little cumbersome to write all the code again for such a small difference in the dataset. Usually in ggplot you can change some parameters (is that the right term?) making the right operations with the `p`; for example, i can change the plot colors with `p + scale_color_manual(values=rainbow(3))`. Of course, this is just a silly example, but it gets really tiresome when I have a really detailed plot, with many tweaks everywhere.

So basically, what I would like to know is if there is some way, like a function `x` such that I can do this:

```
p + x(data = new_data)
```

and get the same as with code chunk 2.

Thanks a lot,
Juan

Comment: Am I missing something?  If you use df<-mtcars for chunk one and the ggplot expression starts ggplot(df, .... you can later assign to the object df subset(mtcars, disp > 200)?  No need to touch your heavily tweaked ggplot code then.

Comment: Indeed, I don't have to tweak the code again, but I have to run all the ggplot commands all over. If I want both plots in the same script I have to copy and paste all the code again (my goal is to run everything with `source`). That is not really that bad in principle, but my script is growing real quick and becoming a little monster. One solution is to make a function for the plot, but then I would be making 1 function for each plot, which seems cumbersome too. So, there, I was hoping that hidden deep in `ggplot` there would be a function to do what I'll like ...

Comment: Ah, so you would like a little for loop in the ggplot call!  Something like ggplot(data = for(i in two-or-more datasets), aes(....    And have ggplot run through both datasets on the same code.  Beyond my humble abilities, for sure, but wizards at R may have an answer!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think it can be done very easily with the ggplot %+% operator.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, color=factor(cyl))) + geom_point(shape=21, size=4)
print(p)

p2<-p %+% mtcars[mtcars$disp>200,]
print(p2)
```

Comment: Can you explain in your own words what exactly the '%+%' operator does?

Comment: @rmutalik it is explained at https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/gg-add.html

Comment: It was indeed explained at the referenced uri, just that it was not immediately noticeable at first. Anyway, to quote from the reference: `To replace the current default data frame, you must use %+%, due to S3 method precedence issues.`

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the chunk2:

```
ggplot(mtcars[mtcars$disp>200,], aes(mpg, wt, color=factor(cyl)))+
geom_point(shape=19, size=4)
```

If you want both of them in one plot:

```
ggplot() + 
geom_point(data=mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, color=factor(cyl)),shape=21, size=4)+
geom_point(data=mtcars[mtcars$disp>200,], aes(mpg, wt, color=factor(cyl)),shape=19, size=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the question is re-phrased as, "How can I avoid writing repeated code to make similar plots with different data?", one answer is to use functions that apply to a ggplot object:

```
my_plot <- function (p) {
    p + aes(color=factor(cyl)) + geom_point(shape=21, size=4)
}

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt))
p2 <- ggplot(newdata, aes(mpg, wt))

p1 <- my_plot(p1); print(p1)
p2 <- my_plot(p2); print(p2)
```

This stuffs all the shared plot parameters in one place, making the code clearer and easing maintenance. The code still runs for each plot object, of course.

You can of course arbitrarily complicate things by combining functions (a recent example from my own work):

```
p2 <- by_gene(stacked_bars(my_plot(p2)))
```

Comment: this technique is very basic and not ggplot-friendly. moreover, could be more easily rewritten using `%>%` and without rewriting variables.