# scale_fill_manual default breaks: how to assign

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm elaborating a function to create a ggplot plot in order to create multiple similar plots later. Some of the plots require customized breaks, so I store breaks in sc_fill_breaks variable.

The problem is that the legend is missing when I set sc_fill_breaks to NULL, so the question is how to preserve the default breaks value when needed?.

```
p <- ggplot(data) + 
    geom_polygon( ... )+
scale_fill_gradientn(title    = sc_fill_title, 
                     colors   = sc_fill_value, 
                     breaks   = sc_fill_breaks,
                     na.value = gradientn_na_val)
```

**Update**

To preserve the default legend breaks has to be set to waiver(), not NULL

Reproducible example:

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)
library(rvest)


nc <- read_sf(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))

br_w <- waiver()
ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn("Area",colors = viridis(10)
                     ) +
  ggtitle("Area of counties in North Carolina") +
  theme_bw()


ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn("Area",colors = viridis(10), breaks = NULL
  ) +
  ggtitle("Area of counties in North Carolina") +
  theme_bw()

ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn("Area",colors = viridis(10), breaks = br_w
  ) +
  ggtitle("Area of counties in North Carolina") +
  theme_bw()
```

P.S. Still don't know why the legend disappears after setting breaks to NULL

Comment: Can you provide an example? It's not very clear why your legends will disappear

Comment: yeah waiver() is ok.

Comment: Consider moving that "update" section to an answer, and then click the check box (ie, answering your own question).  Make sure to include how you loaded `nc` so someone can reproduce it more easily  (eg, `nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")[1], quiet=TRUE)`)

Answer (score 0):

Hold back the call to `scale_fill_gradientn()` for only the individual plots. Move the labels to `labs()`.

```r
# Define the base plot
p_base <- ggplot(data1) + 
  geom_polygon( ... ) +
  labs(title= sc_fill_title)

# Show the first plot
p_base

# Show the second plot, with a different dataset: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29336964
p_base %+% 
  data2

# Show the third plot, with a different dataset and the specified gradient.
p_base %+% 
  data3 +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colors   = sc_fill_value, 
    breaks   = sc_fill_breaks,
    na.value = gradientn_na_val
  )
```

(I'm doing this blindly without knowing the dataset or the desired plots, so make adjustments.)